# Was Russia properly consecrated to the Immaculate Heart?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, russia, fatima, immaculate-heart

Has a pope already properly consecrated Russia to the Immaculate Heart of Mary, in accordance with the requests of [Our Lady of Fatima](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3111)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pope has yet consecrated Russia to the Immaculate Heart of Mary according to all the requests of Our Lady of Fatima.

[***Fatima: A Spiritual Light for Our Times**: The Great Secret of Fatima* (vol. 3)](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6456) by [Fr. Karl Stehlin](https://knightlibrary.wordpress.com/), ch. 3 "The Refusal of the Consecration of Russia", pp. 64-66:

> On the 13th of July 1917, She announces: ***"I shall come to ask for the consecration of Russia to my Immaculate Heart, and the Communion of Reparation on the First Saturdays. If my requests are heeded, Russia will be converted"***. She doesn't say "my request", but "my requests", that is both requests. On the 13th of June 1929, in Tuy, Our Lady gives 4 conditions for the consecration of Russia. She requires the Pope:
>
> 1. to unite **"with all the bishops of the world"**
> 2. to make the consecration
> 3. of Russia
> 4. to the Immaculate Heart of Mary.
>
> On the 13th of May 1930, Sister Lucia explains further the will of Heaven and adds 2 conditions:
>
> 5. "a solemn act of reparation and consecration of Russia to the Sacred Hearts of Jesus and Mary"
> 6. **"the promise that upon the ending of this persecution** [the persecution of the Church by those following the errors of Russia] **he will approve and recommend the practice of the reparatory devotion already described."**

| Date | The Pope | 1) Order to all the Bishops | 2) Consecration | 3) of Rusia | 4) To the Immaculate Heart of Mary | 5) With a Public Act of Reparation | 6) Approval of the Reparatory Devotion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Oct. 1942 | Pius XII | No | Yes | No *(Note 3)* | Yes | No | No |
| Dec. 1942 | Pius XII | No | Yes | No *(Note 3)* | Yes | No | No |
| July 1952 | Pius XII | No | [Yes](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90231/did-pope-francis-consecration-of-russia-and-ukraine-fulfill-all-the-demands-tha/90247#comment252797_90234) | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| Nov. 1964 | Paul VI | No *(Note 1)* | No *(Note 2)* | No | No | No | No |
| June 1981 | John‑Paul II | No | No *(Note 2)* | No | No | No | No |
| Dec. 1981 | John‑Paul II | No | No *(Note 2)* | No | No | No | No |
| May 1982 | John‑Paul II | No *(Note 1)* | Yes | No *(Note 3)* | No | No | No |
| March 1984 | John‑Paul II | Yes | Yes | No *(Note 3)* | No | No | No |
| [Mar. 2022 | Francis I | [Invitation](https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/comunicazioni/2022/03/18/comunicazione-ai-giornalisti.html) | [Yes](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/prayers/documents/20220325-atto-consacrazione-cuoredimaria.html) | Yes ([and Ukraine](https://fatima.org/news-views/breaking-news-francis-says-he-will-consecrate-russia-to-the-immaculate-heart/#will-this-consecration-be-the-one-we-have-all-long-awaited)) | Yes | No | No] |

> *Note 1:* Paul VI gave no order to the bishops. John-Paul II simply said his act was in "spiritual union" with the bishops.
> *Note 2:* the term used during these acts was "entrust" and not "consecrate".
> *Note 3:* the formula used by Pius XII was: "especially for the peoples who profess for you a particular devotion and among whom there was no home which would not have honoured your venerable icon." Those used by John-Paul II are: "the nations who particularly need this offering (*donatio*) and this consecration" and "the peoples from whom you are expecting the consecration and offering".

Comment: "To unite with all the bishops in the world", is obviously the clear problem, as there are so many schismatic bishops and cardinals esp. during the time of St.JP2, but, even if the numerous bishops was not united to St.JP2, his courage does not impede him to proceed with the consecration. And so St.JP2 proceeded but he got wounded in the process, as we can see the physical impariment after the consecration, as Satan and his devils retaliated. In the case of PF, the schismatic bishops & cardinals were already expose and removed, and very few opposes, but still, PF got wounded. Be wise.-Ave!

Answer (score 1):

**Was Russia properly consecrated to the Immaculate Heart?**

The answer is **Yes**!

Pope St. John Paul II consecrated Russia in 1984 courageously, despite knowing that there are numerous schismatic bishops not in full communion with Rome.

This is a spiritual battle, and for all who are involve in the Ministry of Intercession knows, that when one battle with Satan and his demons, with a handicapped like, having schismatic bishops on your back, intercessors or prayer warriors like St.John Paul II Great will be subject to devils retaliation, as in the case of so many Exorcist Rites or encounters. St.John Paul II could have opted not to proceed, because of the danger of consecrating Russia without the full backing of the bishops of the world, but his great courage and love for the Church, pushes him to fight Satan and his demons to destroy their weapon of communism, with few loyal bishops on his side, but in a Totus Tuus mode.

> The Evidence
>
> In the Congregation of the Doctrine of the Faith’s “The Message of Fatima,” released June 26, 2000, as part of the Holy See’s official publication and interpretation of the secret of Fatima, we read (emphasis added):
>
> Sister Lucia personally confirmed that this solemn and universal act of consecration corresponded to what Our Lady wished (“Sim, està feita, tal como Nossa Senhora a pediu, desde o dia 25 de Março de 1984”: “Yes it has been done just as Our Lady asked, on 25 March 1984”: Letter of 8 November 1989). Hence any further discussion or request is without basis.
>
> [Holy See: The Consecration of Russia has taken place](https://www.marian.org/fatima/about/russia.php)

In the case of Pope Francis, the consecration of Russia and Ukraine (formerly belonging to Russia) was done in a much better union with the Bishops in all the world. How? Pope Francis papacy had expose and had removed lot's of schismatic bishops and cardinals, esp. during the heights of Amoris Laetetia controversy.

From 2015 to 2018 up tho this day, Pope Francis was inspired to issue teachings and guidelines that challenges all the bishops in the world, either they fully obey or be expose as schsimatic, and so, Pope Francis can simply remove them, thereby, producing a more purified Church, ready to consecrate Russia, with great numbers of bishops united to him. But ofcourse, there are still few bishops making noise in the mainstream and social media, voicing their schismatic opposition to Pope Francis papacy.

That is why, Pope Francis consecration of Russia and Ukraine is much better than St.John Paul II the Great, butstill not yet perfect. The perfection of consecration of Russia will happen, once all the schismatic bishops and cardinals still hiding in Rome and in the Universal Church, were already expose and remove.

The perfect consecration of Russia will happen under Pope Francis papacy, because Pope Francis is the "Bishop Dressed in White" and not St.John Paul II the Great.

[Francis in Fatima: "I am the bishop dressed in white."](https://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2017/05/francis-in-fatima-i-am-bishop-dressed.html)

Comment: Prescinding from [the possibility that the post-1958 Sr. Lucy is an imposter](https://sisterlucytruth.org/), Fr. Stehlin raises 11 questions ([_Fatima: A Spiritual Light for Our Times_ vol. 3](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6456) pp. 68-69), the first of which are: "**1.** If the act of consecration performed in 1984 corresponded to what Our Lady wanted, why why would Sr. Lucia have waited 5 years to give a positive response? **2.** Why until 1988 she always stated the contrary, i.e. that the consecration had not yet been done?"

Comment: The consecration was accepted eventhough, it was obvious that the bishops of the world is not fully united to St.JP2. Was it an imperfect consecration? Yes!. But St.JP2 is one courageous soul, and he love the Church so much- Totus Tuus, and so, he proceeded to fight the weapon of Satan- communism. Did St.JP2 win the battle? Yes, but he got wounded, after the consecration, his health frailed. Pope Francis have a better support, but still not perfect. The Church must be reduce to a small church, with all the bishops fully united to the Pope is the perfect scenario as PBXVI predicted.

Comment: Nice post +1. Putin says he will have victory over Ukraine, on May 9, 2022. I hope Our Lady’s victory will be on May 13, 2022.