# Did Pope Francis' consecration of Russia and Ukraine fulfill all the demands that Mary requested at Fatima in 1917?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, russia, fatima, ukraine

**Does the [Consecration to the Immaculate Heart of Mary of Russia and Ukraine](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/prayers/documents/20220325-atto-consacrazione-cuoredimaria.html) on March 25, 2022 by Pope Francis fulfill all of the requests asked for by the Virgin Mary at Fatima in 1917?**

Not being an expert in this domain I would like to know if the [Consecration of Russia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecration_of_Russia) and Ukraine meets all the necessary requirements that Mary asked for in 1917?

On March 17, 2022 the pope invited all the bishops to join him in making this consecration! [(Source)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gWwEjhobnrJnrcMMZ29E__B226k-m2nz/view)

This question was inspired by this question: [Was Russia properly consecrated to the Immaculate Heart?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90095/was-russia-properly-consecrated-to-the-immaculate-heart)

One thing is very obvious: Mary has a very dear love for Russia in her Immaculate Heart.

> On [March 15,] 1917, Tsar Nicholas II abdicated from the throne. That same day, the Reigning Icon of the Mother of God was revealed to a peasant woman in Kolomenskoye. Many believe the reappearance of the icon was an indication that the Virgin Mary was displeased with Russia for dethroning Tsar Nicholas II during the February 1917 Revolution.
>
> The Reigning Icon of the Mother of God is believed to date from the 18th century. It is considered one of the most revered both inside Russia and in Russian emigre circles.
>
> The icon was originally venerated in the Ascension Convent, in the Chertolye neighborhood near the Moscow Kremlin. In 1812, as Napoleon Bonaparte’s Grande Armée approached Moscow during the French invasion of Russia, the icon was taken to the village church in Kolomenskoye for safekeeping and subsequently forgotten until 1917.
>
> At the end of the February Revolution of 1917, on 15 March (O.S. 2 March) 1917, Tsar Nicholas II of Russia abdicated the throne. That same day, Evdokia Adrianova, a peasant woman in the village of Pererva in Moscow Province, dreamed that the Blessed Virgin appeared and spoke to her. She was instructed to travel to the village of Kolomenskoye, where she would find an old icon which, “will change colour from black to red.” - [15th March: Reigning Icon of the Mother of God Revealed](https://tsarnicholas.org/2019/03/15/15th-march-reigning-icon-of-the-mother-of-god-revealed/)

Interestingly, in Russia, both Catholics and Orthodox prayed to Mary on Friday, March 25th, 2022, the latter at the request of Russian Patriarch Kirill of Moscow, Primate of the Russian Orthodox Church, who asked the faithful to do so a day after the Vatican announced Pope Francis’s request.

See this YouTube video: [Pope Francis consecrates Russia & Ukraine to Immaculate Heart](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HE7PUNO185Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Geremia's good answer:

1. to unite "with all the bishops of the world"
2. to make the consecration
3. of Russia
4. to the Immaculate Heart of Mary.

On the 13th of May 1930, Sister Lucia explains further the will of Heaven and adds 2 conditions:

5. "a solemn act of reparation and consecration of Russia to the Sacred Hearts of Jesus and Mary"
6. "the promise that upon the ending of this persecution [the persecution of the Church by those following the errors of Russia] he will approve and recommend the practice of the reparatory devotion already described."

According to what has been said about Pope Francis' consecration. He

1. ["invited the bishops of the whole world"](https://www.vaticannews.va/en/pope/news/2022-03/pope-invites-bishops-to-join-him-in-consecration-of-russia.html)  to 2. [Consecrated 3. Russia 4. to the Immaculate Heart](https://archsa.org/news/archbishop-letter-regarding-consecration-of-russia-and-ukraine)

What about the final 2 conditions?

The Consecration took place after a "[penitential](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/250791/pope-francis-consecration-of-russia-and-ukraine-to-the-immaculate-heart-of-mary) service". So far I do not see any words from Francis recommending the faithful to do reparation. He may or may not yet do this.

Two questions remain that I do not believe we are able to answer yet:

1. To what degree must the Pope instruct the bishops to join him? Must he order them to do so under pain of excommunication, or is simply inviting them enough?
2. What counts as an act of reparation? The words of the consecration prayer involve much deprecation on our part before the consecration itself is said. Was the "penitential service" sufficient for this?

One last point. It is important to note that the Sacred Heart is not mentioned at all in Pope Francis' consecration. Nevertheless we can surely say that, at the very least, this act followed Our Lady's message **more** than any other Pope's.

Comment: "_this act followed Our Lady's message more than any other Pope's_" More than [Pius XII's July 1952 consecration / apostolic letter](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/it/apost_letters/documents/hf_p-xii_apl_19520707_sacro-vergente-anno.html), which explicitly mentioned Russia ("as a few years ago we consecrated the whole world to the Immaculate Heart of the Virgin Mother of God, so now, in a very special way, we consecrate all the peoples of Russia to the same Immaculate Heart")? (Pius XII's seemed to have been only in writing, though…)

Comment: See [this translation](https://risen-from-the-dead.forumotion.com/t357-pius-xii-apostolic-letter-july-7-1952-a-d-russian-people-consecrated#p542) the _Sacro vergente anno_ apostolic letter.

Comment: @Geremia "*peoples* of Russia" is quite *Russia* though!

Comment: Yes, he didn't say "[Bolshevik-usurped](http://www.ihr.org/jhr/v14/v14n1p-4_Weber.html) Russia", "USSR", or anything like that. 

Comment: @Pius XII July 1952 consecration is not even close to Pope John Paul II who knew the Third Secret and was a victim of assassination in 1981 that led him to consecrate Russia immediately  and more powerfully despite so many Bishops not united to him, after his recovery. Pope Francis’ consecration is the most significant as more Bishops are in union with him, plus it was done while the Russia and Ukraine are still fighting, and the world are pleading for peace and humbly seeking Mary's intercession, Our Lady the Queen of Peace.

Answer (score 0):

[Fr. Albert, O.P., of the Fatima Center](https://fatima.org/media/ask-father-albert/) opined in [his March 25, 2022, letter](https://isidore.co/misc/Res%20pro%20Deo/T.O.P./Fr.%20Albert/from%20Fr.%20Albert,%20O.P./TOP%20n.30%20BER%20Annunciation.epub):

> On this feast of the Annunciation of Our Lady Pope Francis, in union with the bishops all over the world, consecrated Russia to the Immaculate Heart of Mary. It is true that this act of consecration was somewhat obscured by extraneous additions and a style that is redolent more of the world than the Catholic faith, but it seems, at least, that the essential words in the act responded to what Our Lady asked for at Fatima. For on June 13, 1929 she said to Sister Lucy :
>
> > The moment has come in which God asks the Holy Father, in union with all the Bishops of the world, to make the consecration of Russia to my Immaculate Heart, promising to save it by this means.
>
> Time will tell in what measure this consecration fulfilled Our Lady’s request, but we can certainly hope for many blessings as a result of it, for even if it did not comply perfectly with what Our Lady asked, it certainly went farther than the consecrations made by previous popes. Even those consecrations were followed by great blessings : the end of the Second World War and the fall of Communism (at least to some degree...) : so we can rightly hope that this one will bring down on the world many graces too and perhaps even the conversion of Russia which Our Lady promised.

On March 23, 2022, Fr. Albert addressed "[How Our Lady's Consecration Challenges the Eastern Orthodox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khf_hRJYAo8)":

- The schismatic Orthodox have valid episcopal Orders.
- They deny the dogma of the Immaculate Conception as defined by Bl. Pope Pius IX in [*Ineffabilis Deus*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52893/1787) (1854).
- Their participation in a consecration to the Immaculate Heart challenges them to accept Pius IX's dogmatic definition of her Immaculate Conception, that she never contracted any sin.